# How to disable a UITextField keyboard without hiding it?

Tags: uikeyboard

I have an animation, during which I want to disable the keyboard but not hide it. I even tried `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`, but that hides the keyboard. I guess it must call `resignFirstResponder`.

Comment: hi Matt, do you have resolved this problem?? can u share it in this page? thank you

Comment: Yes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23699811/242933

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable everything, you can use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

right before you start the animation and

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
```

after the animation finishes, e.g., in its completion block.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the keyboard without dismissing it by doing:

```
NSArray *windows = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows;
if ([windows count] > 1) {
    UIWindow *keyboardWindow = windows[1];
    keyboardWindow.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}
```

But, it's obviously very hackish & fragile, and I'm not sure if it complies with Apple's terms.

Comment: have you use it in developing a product for apple app store?