# iOS: How to access the `UIKeyboard`?

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uikeyboard

I want to get a pointer reference to `UIKeyboard *keyboard` to the keyboard on screen so that I can add a transparent subview to it, covering it completely, to achieve the effect of [disabling the `UIKeyboard` without hiding it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915559/how-to-disable-a-uitextfield-keyboard-without-hiding-it/6457114#6457114).

In doing this, can I assume that there's only one `UIKeyboard` on the screen at a time? I.e., is it a singleton? Where's the method `[UIKeyboard sharedInstance]`. Brownie points if you implement that method via a category. Or, even more brownie points if you convince me why it's a bad idea to assume only one keyboard and give me a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about using [`-[UIApplication beginIgnoringInteractionEvents]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginIgnoringInteractionEvents)?

Also, another trick to get the view containing the keyboard is to initialize a dummy view with `CGRectZero` and set it as the `inputAccessoryView` of your `UITextField` or `UITextView`. Then, get its `superview`. Still, such shenanigans is private/undocumented, but I've heard of apps doing that and getting accepted anyhow. I mean, how else would Instagram be able to make their comment keyboard interactive (dismiss on swipe) like the Messages keyboard?

Comment: How can `beginIgnoringInteractionEvents` be used?

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
// my func
- (void) findKeyboard {

    // Locate non-UIWindow.
    UIWindow *keyboardWindow = nil;
    for (UIWindow *testWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) {
        if (![[testWindow class] isEqual:[UIWindow class]]) {
           keyboardWindow = testWindow;
           break;
       }
    }

    // Locate UIKeyboard.  
    UIView *foundKeyboard = nil;
    for (UIView *possibleKeyboard in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {

        // iOS 4 sticks the UIKeyboard inside a UIPeripheralHostView.
        if ([[possibleKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"]) {
            possibleKeyboard = [[possibleKeyboard subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
        }                                                                                

        if ([[possibleKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"]) {
           foundKeyboard = possibleKeyboard;
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For generic coding please replace if condition of for loop by               
if ([[possibleKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"]) {
            for (__strong UIView *anotherPossibleKeyboard in [possibleKeyboard subviews]) {
                if ([[anotherPossibleKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"]) {
                    foundKeyboard = anotherPossibleKeyboard;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

Answer (score 4):

I found that developerdoug's answer wasn't working on iOS 7, but by modifying things slightly I managed to get access to what I needed. Here's the code I used:

```
-(UIView*)findKeyboard
{
    UIView *keyboard = nil;

    for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows)
    {
        for (UIView *possibleKeyboard in window.subviews)
        {
            if ([[possibleKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"])
            {
                keyboard = possibleKeyboard;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return keyboard;
}
```

From what I could make out, in iOS 7 the keyboard is composed of a `UIPeripheralHostView` containing two subviews: a `UIKBInputBackdropView` (which provides the blur effect on whatever's underneath the keyboard) and a `UIKeyboardAutomatic` (which provides the character keys). Manipulating the `UIPeripheralHostView` seems to be equivalent to manipulating the entire keyboard.

Discaimer: I have no idea whether Apple will accept an app that uses this technique, nor whether it will still work in future SDKs.

Comment: Thanks. But I would use a slightly different check for the keyboard:
```Class keyboardClass = NSClassFromString(@"UIPeripheralHostView");
if ([possibleKeyboard isKindOfClass:keyboardClass])```. Instead of relying on a string description. Should also be a bit more performant.

Comment: great suggestion.  it works well in 7.1.  How can i find the keyboard when its off screen? or is it destroyed and doesnt exist?

Answer (score 1):

Be aware, Apple has made it clear that applications which modify private view hierarchies without explicit approval beforehand will be rejected. Take a look in the Apple Developer Forums for various developers' experience on the issue.

If you're just trying to disable the keyboard (prevent it from receiving touches), you might try adding a transparent UIView that is the full size of the screen for the current orientation. If you add it as a subview of the main window, it *might* work. Apple hasn't made any public method of disabling the keyboard that I'm aware of - you might want to use one of your support incidents with Apple, maybe they will let you in on the solution.

Comment: OK. Is there a way to disable the keyboard without hiding it?

Comment: Are you trying to prevent the keyboard from showing up when a user taps in a text field?

Comment: No, I want to disable it during an animation. Apple's Passcode Lock feature does this when you're setting a passcode.

Comment: The keyboard is in a separate window, so a fullscreen view to block it will not work (if you're adding it to your main window). Check [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows].

Answer (score 1):

For an app I am currently developing I am using a really quick and easy method:

Add this in the header file:

```
// Add in interface
UIWindow * _window;

// Add as property
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView * _keyboard;
```

Then add this code in the bottom of the keyboardWillShow function:

```
-(void) keyboardWillShow: (NSNotification *) notification {

    .... // other keyboard will show code //

    _window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.lastObject;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(allocateKeyboard)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
}
```

This code look for when the keyboard is raised and then allocates the current window. I have then added a timer to allocate the keyboard as there were some issues when allocated immediately.

```
- (void)allocateKeyboard {

    if (!_keyboard) {
        if (_window.subviews.count) {

            // The keyboard is always the 0th subview
            _keyboard = _window.subviews[0];
        }        
    }
}
```

We now have the keyboard allocated which gives you direct "access" to the keyboard as the question asks.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Under iOS 8 it appears you have to jump down the chain more than in the past. The following works for me to get the keyboard, although with custom keyboards available and such I wouldn't rely on this working unless you're running in a controlled environment.

```
- (UIView *)findKeyboard {
    for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
        UIView *inputSetContainer = [self viewWithPrefix:@"<UIInputSetContainerView" inView:window];
        if (inputSetContainer) {
            UIView *inputSetHost = [self viewWithPrefix:@"<UIInputSetHostView" inView:inputSetContainer];
            if (inputSetHost) {
                UIView *kbinputbackdrop = [self viewWithPrefix:@"<_UIKBCompatInput" inView:inputSetHost];
                if (kbinputbackdrop) {
                    UIView *theKeyboard = [self viewWithPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard" inView:kbinputbackdrop];
                    return theKeyboard;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}


- (UIView *)viewWithPrefix:(NSString *)prefix inView:(UIView *)view {
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        if ([[subview description] hasPrefix:prefix]) {
            return subview;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: will this prevent app store approval?

Comment: @matteok This alone - I don't think so. Whatever you plan to do with the keyboard though probably would. I used it for specific enterprise reasons.

Comment: What if you apply a transform to the keyboard-window during a transition?