# How to implement drag-to-hide-keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

How can I implement the drag-to-hide-keyboard gesture? Similar to Facebook's Messenger and Messages app on iOS.
In Messages app or FB app, Skype app, etc..., if user drags from outside to inside of keyboard frame, keyboard will move as user's touch drags toward the bottom. It means the keyboard may be only appear just a half on screen when the finger still on touch screen.
I've searched but can't find any info about this.
Is it native feature or do we have to custom it? If custom, how can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIScrollView - Move keyboard with touch drag like iOS 7 mail app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335103/uiscrollview-move-keyboard-with-touch-drag-like-ios-7-mail-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can use

`scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;`

Or you can add a tap gesture recognizer and add target to dismiss your keyboard using resignFirstResponder.
hope it helps!

Comment: Great!! In my case, I mention to UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive mode. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work if you add `scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;`
or `[self.view endediting = YES];`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
UIScrollView.keyboardDismissMode
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using code below, using when scroll view to hidden keyobard.

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

or you can resgister gesture for view you want touch to hidden keyboard and put code

```
self.view.endEditing(true)
```

into action of gesture