# How to show/hide keyboard smoothly on drag in iOS Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, keyboard

I can show keyboard by using `textField.becomeFirstResponder()` or can hide keyboard by using `textField.resignFirstResponder()`.

You may notice in iPhone default message app, when we scroll (or drag) to bottom, the keyboard hides smoothly. And even if we start scroll (or drag) to upside by not touching the bottom, the keyboard shows dynamically.

If I have scrollview or user drag to bottom then how can I implement that.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIScrollView - Move keyboard with touch drag like iOS 7 mail app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335103/uiscrollview-move-keyboard-with-touch-drag-like-ios-7-mail-app)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a `UIScrollView` (or a `UITableView`/`UICollectionView` since they inherit from `UIScrollView`) you can simply set `keyboardDismissMode` property to `interactive`.

Objective-C :
    `self.scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;`

Swift
    `self.scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive`

As usual, [more in the docs.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiscrollview/1619437-keyboarddismissmode)

Comment: How are they able to start the dismissal at the top of the textfield and not at the top of the keyboard? Is there anyway to account for that extra height?

Comment: @Stefan you set the textfield as the `inputAccessoryView` of the view controller and make the view controller first responder by overriding `canBeFirstResponder` and returning `true`

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to dismiss keyboard when touch or drag

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for any object inherit from UIScrollView you can either to set (Dismiss on drag) for Keyboard option from the Attributes inspector or to use below code for swift:

```
self.scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
```